# Web Scraping Columns from Web with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have this website that I want to extract the first 4 columns. But its not working. Im a begginner in WebScraping, any help would be amazing guys:

```
https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2017-nba-predictions/
```

I want to extract each column: `ELO -- CARM-ELO` e so on

This is what Ive done so far:

```
url_nba <- 'https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2017-nba-predictions/'

webpage_nba <- read_html(url_nba)

data_nba.1 <- html_nodes(webpage_nba,'.num elo original desktop')
data_nba.2 <- html_nodes(webpage_nba,'.num elo carmelo')
```

And after this I would like to put in a dataframe.

Any help?

Comment: you say the first four columns which would be elo, carmelo, 1-Week Change and Team Logo. Is that really the case? And  if so, how do you want logo handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you get equal length lists of nodes you can use css selectors to target which ever columns you want and cbind then convert to dataframe as an alternative. The selectors below lead to a clean output dataframe.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

page <- read_html('https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2017-nba-predictions/')
df <- setNames(data.frame(cbind(
  html_text(html_nodes(page, 'td.original')),
  html_text(html_nodes(page, 'td.carmelo')),
  html_text(html_nodes(page, '.change')),
  html_text(html_nodes(page, '.team a'))
)),c('elo','carmelo','1wkchange','team'))

print(df)
```

Comment: Many thanks! But I have a not vlever question: why the tag related to the collumn `elo` is `td.original`and its not `.num elo original desktop`what am I missing?

Comment: _num elo original desktop_ is a multi-valued class attribute i.e. there are multiple values for the class attribute. This is more fragile as greater chance one or more could change and is also more values to match on so potentially slower - so you wan;t shorer selectors; including using single class of multi-value where possible (choose carefully). Finally, it matches on th as well as td. I wanted to match only the actual td elements with the shortest, and fastest, possible selector. The td.original uniquely identified elements of interest and class css selector is second fastest (after id).

Comment: Ive no words! Thanks! Iam starting web scraping by R. If I want to improve my skill do yoou suggest any study to do? Study HTML language would help me?

Comment: Understanding basic html and css selectors up to and including advanced ones would be helpful. If you visit my profile you will see a number of links shared in the about section.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the HTML code the table is a bit mis-shaped.  One approach is to grab then entire table and then collect the Elo scores.

Looking for the css tag "table", three tables were found.  Manually looking at each one, table 3 was the one of interest.

```
library(rvest)
url_nba <- 'https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2017-nba-predictions/'
webpage_nba <- read_html(url_nba)

#collect the tables from the page
tables <- html_nodes(webpage_nba,'table')

#Process the table of interest (returns a list of 1)
resultdf <- tables[3] %>% html_table(fill=TRUE)
resultdf <- resultdf[[1]]
```

The variable "resultdf" is a Dataframe of the table of interest.  Since there were some hidden fields and other non standard information, some clean up is needed to remove the first couple of rows, rename the columns and remove the blank columns.

Comment: Many thanks! whta u mean by: `HTML code the table is a bit mis-shaped`?

Comment: If you look at resultdf, the first two rows are blank, the column headings are in row 3.  All of this is easily fixed if you take a look at the table.